# Python state channel client

Tags: solidity, web3js, blockchain, private-blockchain, python

Stumbled upon this piece of Solidity code which is an Ethereum payment channel :

https://github.com/mattdf/payment-channel

How am I to write a Python client that interacts with it over Web3 ?

What is my Python code supposed to do in order to transfer data over the channel ?

My aim is to eventually write "pings" from many clients to the state channel, after all clients pinged I want to move on to the next one and then, using Merkel Tree write to the blockchain once every X minutes.

Comment: Are you looking for web3.py? http://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

Answer (score 1):

Although [this code](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/32928/22865) is for geth, it will help you understand how to properly use a state channel.